# Tradeoff between reconstruction and retrieval objectives

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

### Question summary

I recently came across the idea that reconstruction and retrieval are two opposing objectives. In particular, optimising a model with regard to a mean squared error (MSE) loss should yield bad retrieval scores, and vice-versa.

I don't understand why this would be the case: to me, optimising a retrieval loss should be good for retrieval and reconstruction objectives. Indeed, to me, good retrieval scores indicate some understanding of the geometry of the manifold / distribution one is trying to learn, and therefore reconstruction should benefit from this.

Can someone explain why there is such tradeoff and give references which document it?

### Concrete example and references

A recent paper [1] tackles reconstruction of images from brain signal. They train a model which takes brain signal as input and yields two distinct outputs. Both outputs are latent representations of the image currently seen by the individual being scanned. Each of these outputs optimises for a different objective function:

- the first output minimises the MSE to ground truth latents
- the second output minimises a retrieval loss to ground truth latents

Some layers producing these outputs are shared, some are specific to each output. They are trained together on a compound objective function which is a weighted sum of the two aforementioned objective functions.

```
           Input
             │
             ▼
        ┌──────────┐
        │  Common  │
        └────┬─────┘
             │
     ┌───────┴─────────┐
     ▼                 ▼
┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐
│ Branch 1 │     │ Branch 2 │
└────┬─────┘     └─────┬────┘
     │                 │
     ▼                 ▼
  Output 1         Output 2
```

Authors state several times that there is a tradeoff between these two objectives, but I don't understand why:

> Specialized submodules for retrieval (using contrastive learning) and reconstruction (using a diffusion prior) enable a single model to achieve state-of-the-art results across both tasks even though the objectives exhibit a tradeoff.

> This is because there is a tradeoff between reconstruction and retrieval objectives and a model cannot effectively learn a single embedding space that does well on both.

[1] Scotti, Paul S., Atmadeep Banerjee, Jimmie Goode, Stepan Shabalin, Alex Nguyen, Ethan Cohen, Aidan J. Dempster, et al. ‘Reconstructing the Mind’s Eye: FMRI-to-Image with Contrastive Learning and Diffusion Priors’. arXiv, 29 May 2023. http://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18274.